# How to generate a dropdown input with a Django ModelForm?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
from django.db import model

class Fruit(models.Model):
    fruit_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And A form like this:

```
from django import forms 
from .models import SomeModel

class FruitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    some_input = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        model = Fruit
        fields = ['fruit_name']
```

[This](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-create-a-drop-down-list-in-a-Django-form.php) guide shows me how to create a dropdown like this:

```
fruit = [
    ('orange', 'Oranges'),
    ('cantaloupe', 'Cantaloupes'),
    ('mango', 'Mangoes'),
    ('honeydew', 'Honeydews'),
]
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    some_input = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    favorite_fruit = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=FRUIT_CHOICES))
```

What I want to happen is for the key/value tuple list to generate based on the fruit_id and fruit_name columns of the `Fruit` model, without the need to manually insert the data into the `FruitForm`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you do that with a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField):

```
from django import forms

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    some_input = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    favorite_fruit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Fruit.objects.all())
```

In your `Fruit` model, you then implement the `__str__` method to decide how to *render* your fruit. Here that would be:

```
from django.db import model

class Fruit(models.Model):
    fruit_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fruit_name
```

You can alter the `queryset=` parameter, for example to filter the queryset in advance. For example if you only want to show `Fruit` that starts with an `A`, you can filter like:

```
from django import forms

# example: only show fruit that starts with an A
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    some_input = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    favorite_fruit = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Fruit.objects.filter(fruit_name__startswith='A')
    )
```